# How to make the control to wait in javascript till the call made to applet gets response which ideally works in JRE1.6V?

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have the below code which usually runs good with JRE 1.6.32 but when we upgraded to JRE 1.7.0_15 the call to applet is not fetching any response .
I even tried to use setTimeout() but it is not working , is their any way to get the response from the applet in JRE 1.7V .??
**Code  :**

```
openPlsWait();//-->**Will open a popup showing the user to wait**
var Refresh  = document.Grid.retry(datesIncreament,aForm.txt_retry.value);//**Call   to   applet where it will wait for the boolean response value.**
if(Refresh)
{
parent.frames["main"].document.OnePlusCal.refresh();//upon receiving the response the applet will refresh
}   
closePlsWait();//**Close the opened popup**
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

1. [Sign you applet](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) with an official certificate
2. Set the [attributes](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/7u45_caller_allowable_codebase_and) are correctly set
3. See the LiveConnect (JavaScript<->Java Applet) [changes](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/liveconnect_changes_in_7u45)